# Loading flex Modules from an XML file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to parse an xml file and load Flex modules dynamically in my application. But it loads only the last module everytime. I have a singleton class which does the parsing and loading of modules. Here is the class

```
package
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
import mx.modules.IModuleInfo;
import mx.modules.ModuleLoader;
import mx.modules.ModuleManager;

public class VappModuleManager
{

    private static var _instance:VappModuleManager;
    private static const MODULE_PATH:String="./com/emc/vapp/"; 
    private static const MANIFEST_PATH:String="module-manifest.xml";
    private var _module:IModuleInfo;
    private var _handler:Function;
    private var loader:URLLoader; 
    public function VappModuleManager(object:SingletonEnforcer)
    {

    }

    public function set handler(handler:Function):void
    {
        _handler=handler;
    }

    public static function get instance():VappModuleManager
    {
        if(_instance==null)
        {
            _instance=new VappModuleManager(new SingletonEnforcer());               
        }

        return _instance;
    }


    public function load():void
    {
        loader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
        loader.load(new URLRequest(MANIFEST_PATH));
    }

    private function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        Alert.show("Event Completed");
        var manifest:XML=new XML(event.target.data);
        Alert.show(manifest.module.length());

        for (var index:int=0;index<manifest.module.length();index++)
        {
            Alert.show(MODULE_PATH+manifest.module[index].@name);
            _module=ModuleManager.getModule(MODULE_PATH+manifest.module[index].@name);
            _module.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY,_handler);
            _module.load();
        }
    }


}
}
internal class SingletonEnforcer    {}
```

I use the above class as follows.

```
moduleManager=VappModuleManager.instance;

moduleManager.handler=myhandler;

moduleManager.load();
```

I understand the problem is with eventlistener for variable "_module" but dont know how to solve it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `IModuleInfo.load` is asynchronous so your `for` loop has run completely before any of the modules have loaded. Also, your class level `_module` property is overwritten by a new `Module` instance each time the loop iterates.

I'd suggest loading each module sequentially by waiting for the `READY` event and initiating the load of the next module only when it has fired. I'd also fire an event when all the modules are loaded instead of executing a callback function as this will give you more flexibility (multiple objects can listen for an event for example).

The following isn't tested, but should give you the idea:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
    import mx.modules.IModuleInfo;
    import mx.modules.ModuleLoader;
    import mx.modules.ModuleManager;

    public class VappModuleManager
    {

        private static var _instance:VappModuleManager;

        private static const MODULE_PATH:String="./com/emc/vapp/"; 
        private static const MANIFEST_PATH:String="module-manifest.xml";

        private var loader:URLLoader; 
        private var manifest:XML; 
        private var loadCount:int = 0; // track loaded modules

        public function VappModuleManager(object:SingletonEnforcer)
        {

        }

        public static function get instance():VappModuleManager
        {
            if(_instance==null)
            {
                _instance=new VappModuleManager(new SingletonEnforcer());               
            }

            return _instance;
        }


        public function load():void
        {
            loader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
            loader.load(new URLRequest(MANIFEST_PATH));
        }

        private function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            manifest =new XML(event.target.data);

            // load the first module
            loadModule();
        }

        private function loadModule() {
            // Use a locally scoped variable to avoid writing over the previous instance each time.
            // You could push these onto an array if you need to be able to access them later
            var module:IModuleInfo = ModuleManager.getModule(MODULE_PATH+manifest.module[loadCount].@name);
            module.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, moduleReadyHandler);
            module.load();
        }

        private function moduleReadyHandler(event:ModuleEvent) {
            // Remove the event listener on the loaded module
            IModuleInfo(event.target).removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, moduleReadyHandler);

            loadCount ++;

            // Are there still modules in the manifest to load?            
            if (loadCount < manifest.module.length()) {
                // Yes... load the next module
                loadModule();
            } else {
                // No... we're all finished so dispatch an event to let subscribers know
                dispatchEvent(new Event("complete"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```